# Excel spell check using C#

Tags: c#, excel, spell-checking

some one just help me with this!
why isn't this code working.I don't find much tutorials on the internet too.

```
Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
xlWorkShee=(Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);                 
xlApp.SpellingOptions.UserDict = "CUSTOM.DIC";     
var udict = xlApp.SpellingOptions.UserDict;
xlWorkSheet.CheckSpelling();        
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Sstring";           
string tsql = "select nvalue from [role report]";
OleDbDataAdapter tda = new OleDbDataAdapter(tsql, con);
DataTable tdt = new DataTable();
con.Open();
tda.Fill(tdt);
con.Close();
int count = 0;

for (int x = 0; x<500; x++)
{
    if (tdt.Rows[x]["nvalue"].ToString()!= "")
    {
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[x+2, 1] = tdt.Rows[x]["nvalue"].ToString();
        count++;
    }
}

for (int k=0; k<count; y++)
{
     //bool t = false;
    if (xlWorkSheet.Cells[k+2, 1].ToString() != "")
    {
        if ((xlApp.CheckSpelling(xlWorkSheet.Cells[k+2, 1].ToString())))
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[k+2, 2] = "chk";
    }
}

try
{
    xlWorkBook.SaveAs("spellspell.xls",Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
    misValue,Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,misValue,                      
    misValue, misValue,misValue,misValue);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ }
xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
xlApp.Quit();

releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
releaseObject(xlApp);

MessageBox.Show("Excel file created, you can find the file c:\\csharp-Excel.xls")
```

My output is supposed to have the string "chk" in the cell besides every wrongly spelled word. But the output doesn't show that.

Comment: The correct usage of xlApp.CheckSpelling() should help me here. Anyone used this before???!

Comment: You could start by adding a Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message) at your catch block.

Comment: That's one nasty spaghetti code! Can't believe someone's writing a C# software like this... No wonder you can't find the problem.

Comment: @walther I'd like it if you can be resourceful man. I just need to know the format to use .CheckSpelling() function.

Comment: You need to separate your function to separate methods. Then start with the already suggested approach - use a debugger and try to find the source of the problem. You mix and match various abstract layers, I can see some db access, some xml library and who knows what else. If you format your code properly according to the known OOP coding standards, you'll surely find out that it's suddenly much easier to find an error.

Answer (score 1):

This code worked finally for me!!!. Pulled the data from Access Db and stored as a column in Excel and used the code to identify the wrongly spelled words in the excel sheet.

```
  for (int y = 0; y <count; y++)
    {
    try
       {
   if(xlWorkSheet.Range["A" + (y + 2) + ""].Value.ToString() != "")
      {
     if (!(xlApp.CheckSpelling(xlWorkSheet.Range["A" + (y + 2) + ""].Value.ToString(), 
             udict, 1033)))
           {
              xlApp.Visible = false;

              xlWorkSheet.Cells[y + 2, 2] = "chk";            
                 }
              }
          }
     catch(Exception)
      {
       }
      }
```

The selection of the cell was the part which got me busy. Finally

```
 if (!(xlApp.CheckSpelling(xlWorkSheet.Range["A" + (y + 2) + ""].Value.ToString(), 
         udict, 1033)))
```

worked. It showed "chk" against every wrongly spelled word.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to check out the APIs on MSDN, here's the links =>
**Worksheet.CheckSpelling:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.checkspelling(v=vs.100).aspx

**Application.CheckSpelling:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.checkspelling

According to the definition, CheckSpelling method does this, "Checks the spelling of a single word. Returns **True** if the word is found in one of the dictionaries; returns **False** if the word isn't found."

That means, if any word is misspelled, CheckSpelling should return **False** (depends on whether the word is in the given dictionary or not)

In your code, you were doing

```
if ((xlApp.CheckSpelling(xlWorkSheet.Cells[k+2, 1].ToString())))
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[k+2, 2] = "chk";
```

which I think is the opposite to what you were trying to achieve. (`"have the string "chk" in the cell besides every wrongly spelled word"`)

So just add ! to your if statement

```
if (!(xlApp.CheckSpelling(xlWorkSheet.Cells[k+2, 1].ToString())))
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[k+2, 2] = "chk";
```

and that should be what you were after.

Also, for code clarity and readability, I'd highly suggest that you break down your code into functions, methods, etc. And be careful about calling `xlWorkSheet.Cells[k+2, 1].ToString()`, as it might give you Null exception without checking the value first.

Comment: thanks man! you actually understood what I mean. I did use it the otherway, when I used the other way round , I got "chk" besides all my words why do you think that happened?. If you can tell me if ti could be because of the parameters that i need to key for the .CheckSpelling to work . Ideally it is .CheckSpelling(string,default dictionary, dictionary language) . As you can see I didn't mention that and I presumed the function would assume default values. Any Ideas on that ?? I searched net , very had to find a person who has used Application.CheckSpelling in a C# code. Thanks!

Comment: I guess you haven't looked at the links, have you? The usage is actually all in there. If you just want to use default spellchecking , you could do this `.CheckSpelling(xlWorkSheet.Cells[k+2, 1].ToString(), Type.Missing, Type.Missing);`

Comment: I saw both the links already man.Before even I posted the question on the forum. Well , see I used '!' now . The result that I get is "chk" against every string even the correctly spelled words. Now that's something I'm worried about.
@woodykiddy thoughts please!

Comment: I think what you can do is to test just a few words first (hardcoded preferably). Don't pull in data from datasource nor use for loop. Also remove code that sets up using custom dictionary. Could be something not quite right with your custom dictionary.