# How do I check spelling but not show the spell check dialog?

Tags: c#, database, excel, com-interop, spell-checking

How do I prevent viewing the Excel spell check pop up that opens when I run the following code? And also when a spelling correction is made, I want to store the particular cell in an array.

```
xlWorkSheet.CheckSpelling(Type.Missing, true, false, Type.Missing);
```

This code does the proper spell checking but it shows the spell check pop up. I would like to prevent that, and also store all the corrected words in an array.

Comment: Please give your questions meaningful names from now on. How is "Excel spell check using C#" supposed to help anyone searching for help? The fact that you gave it exactly the same title as your previous question should tell you that it's not a good title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the CheckSpelling method of Excel's Application object, rather than the Worksheet object or Range object, it will return a True or False and not display the dialog.  It only checks one word, though, so you have to loop through the range cell-by-cell, then split the cell's contents on the space character, then loop through the array of words and pass them into Application.CheckSpelling.

Comment: very true , I realized this very late. I've got the script on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120082/excel-spell-check-using-c-sharp. Please leave your thoughts , the code now gives me the intended result though.